# How to make sure that back button takes me to section where I was there before I clicked an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-components

I have an HTML page in which there are list of images around 4-5. The HTML code of **individual image (item-detail.component.html) is shown below:**

```
<span class="badge" id="heart-badge{{item.$id}}">
  <div (click)="badgeHeartEmpty()" id="heartHide{{item.$id}}">
    <img id="badge-item-heart-noborder-empty" src="/assets/images/Empty-Heart.png">
  </div>
  <div [style.display]= " 'none' " (click)="badgeHeartFull()" id="heartShow{{item.$id}}">
    <img id="badge-item-heart-noborder-full" src="/assets/images/Full-Heart-Blue.png">
  </div>
</span>

<!-- This is the code which shows item images and item details -->
<a href="/attendee-item/{{item.$id}}">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{item.image_url}}" alt="Card image cap" id="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="auction-item-title">
            <h1 id="auction-item-title">{{item.name}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="auction-item-bid-title">
            <div class="auction-item-title-left">
                <p id="auction-item-bid-title">Current Bid: ${{item.bid}}</p>
                <p id="auction-item-bid-title">Value: ${{item.value}}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="auction-item-title-right">
                <p id="auction-item-bid-title2">About this item</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<bid-button [item]="item"></bid-button>
```

Now if I click above item (**as you can see there is a href tag on it**) then it shows me detailed description of that image **on a new page and that page also has a back button at the top**. Below is the code for back button on that new page:

```
<div class="item-top-bar">
    <div class="item-back-bar">
    <!-- This is the back button and it takes me to home page but instead it should take me to section of image where I was there and clicked it -->
        <p id="item-back-bar-link"><a id="item-back-bar-link" href="/attendee-home"><</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-pagination-bar">
        <a (click)="prevItem()"><p id="item-pagination-bar-text">LAST ITEM</p></a>
        <a (click)="nextItem()"><p id="item-pagination-bar-text">NEXT ITEM</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

Now if I click back button then it takes me to the home page **but instead what I want is it should take me to the section of image where I was before**.

Is this possible to do? I mean if I have may sections of images and **if I click lets say 4th image then it will open detailed description of that fourth image page and now if I press back button then it should take me to fourth section of image where I was before**.

Comment: yes, it's possible. but what have you tried?

Comment: hey.. I have tried using window history stuff but it doesnt work so thats why I was confuse whether its even possible or not.

Comment: then you should include it in question.

Comment: window.history stuff have you looked at pushing and popping states the technology is called `pushState` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back, you should use the back() function in javascript

```js
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

Here is a small example of how to use it, now you can just adapt it to your page

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding the id here

```
<p id="item-back-bar-link">
   <a id="item-back-bar-link" href="/attendee-home/{{id}}">
       // ....
  </a>
</p>
```

Now there are multiple way to get the `id`. You can use the `window.location` properties or if in same component pass this `id` to a property binding

Comment: Do you mean this ? `<div class="item-back-bar">
            <p id="item-back-bar-link">
                <a id="item-back-bar-link" href="/attendee-home/{{id}}">
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>`

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but it didn't work. There is no hyperlink for this id `attendee-home/{{id}`

Comment: Any comment on my previous post ?

Comment: As mentioned in your answer, I have replaced it with the following code `<div class="item-back-bar">
            <p id="item-back-bar-link"> <a id="item-back-bar-link" href="/attendee-home/{{id}">
      <
  </a></p>
        </div>`

Comment: There is no url `href="/attendee-home/{{id}"` for this so it is taking me to the home page again.

Comment: Ok so now `id` becomes a variable , you need to bind this id through component. First thing first when after clicking on the link when you come to new page check are you getting the id from previous page or not

Comment: I will share an example. Let us take this stack overflow url
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892151/how-to-make-sure-that-back-button-takes-me-to-section-where-i-was-there-before-i/49892293?noredirect=1#comment86821647_49892293'

Comment: On clicking an image from the list of 4-5 images, I am getting an `id` on a new page. On clicking an image from the list of 4-5 images from this url  `http://localhost:4200/attendee-home`, it takes me here `http://localhost:4200/attendee-item/4`

Comment: On clicking this link which i have shared check the url you will find something like `#comment86821647_49892293'` at the end

Comment: So that is the reason when you navigate to the url it takes directly to the comment. If you remove the last part it will take you to the page but wll not scroll to the comment section.Here you are trying ti implement same feature

Comment: Ok so now are you able to bind the id which you got from previous page in the new page

Comment: Also on clicking on this `http://localhost:4200/attendee-item/4` it takes me to here `http://localhost:4200/attendee-home`

Comment: On the basis of your comment, I agree I am trying to implement the same. I am wondering what changes I should make in my code.

Comment: ok so what is the url of main page which contains . `http://localhost:4200/attendee-home`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169261/discussion-between-user5447339-and-brk).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. 
On a separate note, having the same ID across multiple levels may not be a good idea.

```
<div class="item-back-bar">
    <!-- This is the back button and it takes me to home page but instead it should take me to section of image where I was there and clicked it -->
        <p id="item-back-bar-link"><a id="back" href="#">Back</a></p>
    </div>

<script>
window.document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function(e){
     window.history.back();
     e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has `Location` which is a service that applications can use to interact with a browser's URL. It is what you need in order to solve your problem. 
See implementation below.

```
<div class="item-back-bar">
    <!-- This is the back button and it takes me to home page but instead it should take me to section of image where I was there and clicked it -->
        <p id="item-back-bar-link"><a id="back" (click)="goBackClicked()">Back</a></p>
    </div>
```

Your ts file should have these lines.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
// component's declarations here
})
class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private _location: Location) {
    }
    goBackClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page is scrolled and you want to maintain your scroll position while coming back from the **detailed description page**, then you can store the current page's vertical scroll position in a service and while navigating back, you can set the scroll position back from service.

Link to [ScrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) in MDN. Also Check [Window.To](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) for scrolling.

Sample Angular project to show `Element.ScrollTop`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdjmny.

Click page1, scroll the sample list to navigate, when u com back, the scoll will be maintained.

Also make sure, in your `[routerLink]` of your **detailed description page** you are linking to the item-detail.component.html component.

Answer (score 0):

y not just get the position of the image when it is clicked with **.position()** and when returned from the image to the page you can  get back to the same position  with **$(window).scrollTop(value)**.

Answer (score 0):

Really theses comments are right. If you want go back page you can use the command window.history.go(-1) or window.history.back()

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor tag for this. You need to give the part of the page you go back to an "id", like "gobackto_id". Then you can use this in your "" element in the "href" like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.be/home#gobackto_id".
```